# How to fix WPAlchemy MetaBox PHP 8 error "must be of type array, null given"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a WordPress website with a theme I purchased from Themeforest and unfortunately the support from the developer is non-existent and I am not experienced in PHP so I am of no use.

Would appreciate if anyone could assist me with my issue.

Here is the error that I'm getting:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, null given in /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-content/plugins/theme_support_eronment/includes/vafpress/includes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php:1163 Stack trace: #0 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-content/plugins/theme_support_eronment/includes/vafpress/includes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php(1163): in_array('page', NULL) #1 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-content/plugins/theme_support_eronment/includes/vafpress/classes/metabox.php(29): WPAlchemy_MetaBox->can_output() #2 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-content/plugins/theme_support_eronment/includes/loader.php(97): VP_Metabox->__construct(Array) #3 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): _bunch_plugin_init('') #4 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-settings.php(623): do_action('init') #7 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-config.php(96): require_once('/usr/www/users/...') #8 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/usr/www/users/...') #9 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/usr/www/users/...') #10 /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-admin/post.php(12): require_once('/usr/www/users/...') #11 {main} thrown in /usr/www/users/bucknfekew/wp-content/plugins/theme_support_eronment/includes/vafpress/includes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 1163

```
$post_type = WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_get_current_post_type();
if (isset($post_type) && ! in_array($post_type, $this->types))
{
    $can_output = FALSE;
}
// filter: output (can_output)
if ($this->has_filter('output'))
{
    $can_output = $this->apply_filters('output', $post_id);
}
return $can_output;
```

I've tried disabling the plugin and that just isn't an option as the theme needs this plugin to run properly.

Unfortunately the server I am running the website on was permanently upgraded to PHP 8.0 minimum so running it on 7.4 is not an option.